# Android Studio 3.3 Canary 13 Attach to Debugger Button is missing

Tags: android, android-studio-3.3

Is the `Attach to Debugger` button removed from Android Studio 3.3 Canary 13?

**Android Studio 3.2**
[image]

**Android Studio 3.3**
[image]

Comment: can you send photo

Comment: Screenshots of Android Studio 3.2 and Android Studio 3.3 Toolbars has been added to the question.

Comment: I don't use Android Studio so take this at face value... Maybe configure the toolbar and see if *Attach to Debugger* is available but unchecked.

Comment: I've searched for all Actions and Options with cmd + shift + a.
Unfortunately, it did not find any similar action. In Android Studio there is an action called: "Attach debugger to Android process"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you have plugin 'Flutter',disable it or do‘t use the latest version .

Comment: Disabling Flutter solved the issue. Attach Debugger to Process is visible again. Thanks

Comment: The flutter plugin version 30.0 fixes this problem and can now be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It will help for someone just try this button!

[image]